# Django serializers: validate function not called

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am trying override `validate()` function to be called by `serializers.is_valid()`, but its not getting called.

**serializer.py**

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255,required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128,required=True)


    def validate(self,data):
       '''
       Check for invalid email.
       & blank email and password. 
       '''

       print 'hey i am in login'

       if data['email'] is '':
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Email cannot be empty.")
       if data['password'] is '':
          raise serializers.ValidationError("Password cannot be empty.")
       try:
          validate_email(data['email'])
       except ValidationError:
          raise serializers.ValidationError("The email is not a valid email address.")
       return data
```

**views.py**

```
class LoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
       data = self.serializer(data=request.data)
       if data.is_valid():
          #do something
       else:
           return Response(data.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

while i call `is_valid()`, the print statement inside `validate()` function is not getting executed.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What data are you passing in the `POST` request?

Comment: `{"email":"xyz","password":""}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are not getting any `print` statements because `validate` function is not being called.

If there is an error in one of the fields say `email`, `validate` function won't be called but since you didn't pass `raise_exception=True` as argument in `is_valid` you are not getting those errors and you assume that `is_valid` is not running.

You could write the `post` method as following:

```
def post(self, request):
   serializer = self.serializer(data=request.data)

   # following will automatically raise an exception if the serialize data is not valid
   serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

   # do something if the serializer is valid
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to raise specific message after validating different fields, you could create a method `validate_<fieldname>` in serializer:

```
def validate_email(self, value):

    if value == '':
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Email cannot be empty.")

    try:
        validate_email(value)
    except ValidationError:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The email is not a valid email address.")

    return value
```

Comment: I tried with `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` but doesnt work, you are right 

"If there is an error in one of the fields say email, validate function won't be called"
but that is what i am trying to capture and report the right message

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? I assume it will raise an exception since the email you have passed i.e. `xyz` is not a valid email.

Comment: I want to avoid auto handle invalid email id. and put custom error message.

Comment: You can use `validate_email` function just like in the updated answer. Since `validate_email` will be called before the validators itself you will get the custom error message first.

Comment: It works only when `email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255,allow_blank=True)`  and captures only when blank is passed. but  for any invalid value xyz its handled automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109526/discussion-between-aman-and-aks).

Comment: For anyone interested that stumbles on this issue as well, I was able to solve this problem by defining email as a CharField instead of an EmailField. ```email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)```

Comment: upvoted! I was struggling with this for hours yesterday and it turns out the error was exactly because one or many of my fields raised an `this field cant be blank/empty` and it silently failed causing the validate function to not be called.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. Try to go with

```
def run_validation(self, data):
...
```

instead of

```
def validation(self, data):
...
```

this should work!